# Python requests url encoding not working

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, python-requests

Directly from the python requests examples is this snippet:

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}  
r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", params=payload)  
print r.url  
u'http://httpbin.org/get?key2=value2&key1=value1'
```

But when I try to pull data from a website (using requests 0.13.0):

```
payload = {'one' : 'one', 'two' : 'two' }  
r = requests.get("http://[ip_removed]/clubs/pairs_results/personal.php", params=payload)
print r.url  
http://[ip_removed]/clubs/pairs_results/
```

That's not correctly encoded at all. Ideas?

EDIT:
Looks like the site issues a 302 redirect. How do I deal with that to get the same html that my browser will see.

Comment: Second code fragment works for me .... Try doing it with your local ip (127.0.0.1) and post the actual example?

Comment: Does your server redirect, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site simply does a `HTTP 302`-redirect here which `requests` follows, so you'll end up on a different url than originally requested. That's not error but the expected behaviour.

If you don't want that, you can add the `allow_redirects=False` keyword argument when sending the request.

And by the way: a google search with `inurl:...` quickly reveals which site you're talking about here, even if you remove the ip...

Comment: So why when I encode the url manually and put it into a browser do I not get redirected? How do I get the same html my browser will get?

Comment: Don't know, maybe you need to set some cookies too? Use some inspection tool (like [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/httpfox/)) to find out what's actually being sent to the server.